# periodically flushing channel in golang

Tags: go

I need to periodically flush contents of a channel.
I did this with len() and I am wondering if there is some better way to do this.

http://play.golang.org/p/YzaI_2c_-F

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    commch := make(chan int, 100)
    go fillchan(commch)
    drainchan(commch)
}

func fillchan(commch chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.Tick(30 * time.Millisecond):
            commch <- rand.Int()
        }
    }
}

func drainchan(commch chan int) {
    for {
        chanlen := len(commch) // get number of entries in channel
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        for i := 0; i <= chanlen; i++ { //flush them based on chanlen
            fmt.Printf("chan len: %s num: %s\n", chanlen, <-commch)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** seems like this is better way to do this
http://play.golang.org/p/4Kp8VwO4yl

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    commch := make(chan int, 1000)
    go fillchan(commch)
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.Tick(1000 * time.Millisecond):
            drainchan(commch)
        }
    }
}

func fillchan(commch chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.Tick(300 * time.Millisecond):
            commch <- rand.Int()
        }
    }
}

func drainchan(commch chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case e := <-commch:
            fmt.Printf("%s\n",e)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** removed select, prevented memory leak with time.Tick
http://play.golang.org/p/WybAhRE3u4

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    commch := make(chan int, 1000)
    go fillchan(commch)
    for _ = range time.Tick(1000 * time.Millisecond) {
        drainchan(commch)
    }
}

func fillchan(commch chan int) {
    for _ = range time.Tick(300 * time.Millisecond) {
        commch <- rand.Int()
    }
}

func drainchan(commch chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case e := <-commch:
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", e)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is one big race condition.

Comment: Why do you want to flush the contents of a channel? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to wait the chan, you've better to use `select { case <-commch: ...`

Comment: Have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/V1Kzl4j5M2Y . The last reply seems to be what you're after.

Comment: Also there's no reason to have a `select` with only one channel op and no default case.

Comment: There's really a lot of wrong code there.  For example, `fillchan` is doing a single-case receive in a select -- but worse, in a for loop.  Just range over the channel.  Creating a new ticker every 300ms is going to surely run you out of memory.  This is probably what you wanted: http://play.golang.org/p/e5_Z4U5VwU

Answer (score 8):

The need to flush away the contents of a channel would be unusual. Channels don't provide this feature - but you can make a goroutine that will behave that way (...if you *really* do want to).

Typically, you would be thinking more about a goroutine that inputs on one channel and outputs on another; both channels carry the same data type. You could in principle model all buffered channels this way; to its clients, the goroutine behaves like an ordinary buffered channel because it passes on what it receives.

Add a third channel into the goroutine, combined with a *select* between it and the input. This will allow you to trigger the emptying of the buffer without race conditions creeping in. Simple.

Now there are three channels connected to the goroutine - two inputs and an output. So, when you design the things that will use it, you can reason about what the semantics of flushing that data are.

**A relative springs to mind.** Consider a goroutine with one input and one output channel. It provides an overwriting buffer of fixed size, i.e. one that is always ready to read from its input channel, even when the output channel is blocked. This will also need a *select* with a default case, but no third channel is needed. Overwriting buffers have a clear use case: when channels and goroutines are wired into loops, deadlock can be quite likely. Overwriting buffers come in handy as one candidate solution for deadlocks because some data is useless when it's late - for example, you could for example throw away mice events in a GUI when the application is too busy to respond to them.

Comment: I see where you're going. I think it might be more proper to maintain a mutex for drainage purposes.

Comment: No, quite the opposite. The point of a CSP process is that its internal state is altered *sequentially* (hence the name). There are never race conditions within goroutines that don't share external state. So mutexes are never needed in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

The `BatchingChannel` from https://github.com/eapache/channels does what you need I think.

Answer (score 1):

When I come across this issue, this is how I handle it.

```
func (s *ReadStream) drain() {
    go func() {
        for b := range s.chan {
            blackhole(b)
        }
    }()
}

func blackhole(b []byte) {}
```

In situations where your select may be blocked context.Context seems like the wrong choice:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return
    default:
        send<-getData()
    }
}
```

If send is full, we are at the mercy of an outside goroutine before we can receive the done signal. This is ok if you're sure the consumers are going to read until the channel closes, but if those consumers can experience error conditions and return, hope is all you can do. In this specific situation, I'm a fan of replacing the context with an internal quit chan and waitgroup, and then provide a public Kill() method. As long as I'm absolutely sure I'm ok throwing away the data, of course.

```
func (s *ReadStream) Kill() {
    s.quit<-struct{}{}
    s.drain()   // ensure goroutine sees the cancel
    s.wg.Wait() // wait for goroutine to see the cancel
    s.close()
}
```